# similar matrices have the same bandwidth?

Tags: matrices

If $A$ is symmetric with bandwidth $p$ then $A_+ = Q^{T} A Q$, where $Q$ is orthogonal, is orthogonally similar to $A$. How can we show/prove that $A_+$ also has bandwidth $p$ ?

Comment: By bandwidth, do you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix#Matrix_bandwidth)?  Also, what is $A_+$?

Comment: yes, and I defined $A_+$ as above.

Comment: Oh, I see, $Q$ is an arbitrary orthogonal matrix then.

Answer (score 2):

This is not necessarily the case.  For example: the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{3&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}; \quad A_+ = \pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1}
$$
Clearly do not have the same bandwidth.

Comment: What is the $Q$ here?

Comment: One valid $Q$ is
$$
Q = \pmatrix{
1/\sqrt 3 & 1 / \sqrt 3 & 1 / \sqrt 3\\
1/\sqrt 2 & -1/\sqrt 2 & 0\\
1/\sqrt 6 & 1/\sqrt 6 & -\sqrt{(2/3)}
}
$$
To be sure though, any two symmetric matrices with the same eigenvalues are orthogonally similar.